# Problems with determining convergence of integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration, improper-integrals

It should be easy but I'm not sure... For which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the following integral is convergent:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{|y-x|^\alpha}dxdy \ \ ?$$

I get for all $\alpha \neq 1,2$ but I think it is wrong.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I would say $\alpha <1$

Answer (score 2):

Make a change of variables: $t=x-y$, $s=x+y$ so you integral becomes something like (up to constants):
$$
\iint \frac {1}{|t|^\alpha} \, dt\, ds
$$
which has the same convergence as
$$
\int_0^1 \frac 1 {t^\alpha} \, dt = C\left[t^{1-\alpha}\right]_0^1 < +\infty
$$
if $\alpha<1$.

Comment: Yes! Now I see that, one gets $\alpha < 1$ and $\alpha < 2$ when evaluating the limits.. so $\alpha < 1$ indeed.. The change of variables is smart as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Make the change of variable $u=x$ and $v=y-x$.

This yields
$$
\int_{u=0}^1\int_{v=-u}^{1-u}\frac{1}{|v|^\alpha}dvdu.
$$

The inner integral converges if and only if $\alpha<1$, in which case it is equal to
$$
\int_{-u}^0\frac{1}{(-v)^\alpha}dv+\int_0^{1-u}\frac{1}{v^\alpha}dv=\frac{u^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}+\frac{(1-u)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}.
$$

Then the remaining $u$ integral is improper at $0$ and $1$, where it converges if and only if $\alpha -1<1$, ie $\alpha<2$.

So your integral converges if and only if
$$
\alpha<1.
$$

Note you can even compute it.